# How to prove this is a tautology

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$\forall x : (p(x) \wedge \neg q(x)) \vee \exists x: \neg p(x) \vee \neg \exists x: q(x)$

The problem is I know that this is a tautology, but I don't know how to prove it. Can anyone can help me?

Comment: Is somebody demanding a proof from you? If so, you need to tell us which particular formal proof system they want you to use -- there are many possible ones which are structured quite differently (even though they prove the same things), and a hint that works with one may well be useless for another system. Be sure to explain _exactly_ what the axioms and rules you have available are -- not just their names (rule names and their meanings vary considerably from book to book).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

Here is a way without EI
(a lot quicker,too):

$\forall x : (p(x) \wedge \neg q(x)) \vee \exists x: \neg p(x) \vee \neg \exists x: q(x) \Rightarrow$

$\forall x : \neg(\neg p(x) \vee  q(x)) \vee \exists x: \neg p(x) \vee \neg \exists x: q(x)\Rightarrow$

$\exists x : (\neg p(x) \vee  q(x)) \vee \exists x: \neg p(x) \vee \neg \exists x: q(x)\Rightarrow$

$\exists x : \neg p(x) \vee  \exists x: q(x) \vee \exists x: \neg p(x) \vee \neg \exists x: q(x)\Rightarrow$

$\exists x : \neg p(x) \vee  (\exists x: q(x) \vee \neg \exists x: q(x))\vee \exists x: \neg p(x)\Rightarrow$

$\exists x : \neg p(x) \vee  T \vee \exists x: \neg p(x)\Rightarrow $

$\exists x : \neg p(x) \vee  T \Rightarrow  T$

Comment: May i ask you question? Between thirt and fourth transformation. How it is possible that you have change "x" for "a" in 2 predicate when you delete $\exists$ . Isn't this possible only for "$\forall$"?

Comment: Hi! It is possible for $\exists$, but only if the name we choose (in my case "a") has not occurred earlier in the proof.

Comment: Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation . Are you familiar with this rule?

Comment: To this moment no, is this work exactly like 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation ?? There is some difference between those two? except universal and existential ?

Comment: Yes, it works like universal instantiation, but note that the letter you choose in existential instantiation should be a new one (not one that occurred earlier in the proof). Whereas in universal instantiation you can choose any letter you like.

Comment: Could you look on my post bellow\above ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking it up in words.  The second two conditions are:

"there is an $x$ such that $p(x)$ is false"

"there is no $x$ such that $q(x)$ is true"

You need to show that if neither of these conditions holds (that is, both of these statements are false), then necessarily the first one ("for every $x$, $p(x)$ is true and $q(x)$ is false") must be true.

Can you see how to prove that?

Answer (score 0):

The following proof uses a proof checker to make sure I am not violating any rules:

[image]

On line 1, I assume the negation of what I want to prove.

Between lines 2 and 8, I use De Morgan rule (DeM), conjunction elimination (∧E) and change of quantifiers (CQ) to arrive at lines 5 and 8. I will attempt to use existential elimination and universal elimination to derive a contradiction using these lines.

To attempt to eliminate the existential statement on line 5, I assume that I can replace the variable $x$ with the name $a$. I will attempt to derive a contradiction (⊥). I am able to do that by using universal elimination from line 8 on line 12.  Because this is a universal elimination I can use any name and so I reuse the name $a$ which will help me derive the contradiction. Lines 11 and 12 are now contradictory and so I can derive the desired contradiction on line 13.  That allows me to discharge the assumption on line 9 and place the contradiction on line 14 justified by existential elimination (∃E).

The contradiction on line 14 is what I need to use indirect proof (IP) to derive the result I sought.

Links to the proof checker and the *forallx* text associated with it are below.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf